# meaning of pre-merger and post-merger

Tags: sentence-meaning

> Comcast plans to walk away from Time Warner Cable deal. Comcast could announce as early as Friday that they will ditch their plans to buy Time Warner Cable. Regulators plan to nix the $45 billion proposal which would consolidate the nation's two largest cable companies. The **post-merger** company would have had access to nearly half of the Internet market nationwide. Consumers and advocacy groups have vigorously opposed the deal, arguing that the deal would give one company too much clout in video and Internet access.

Could you simplify the meaning of "post-merger" and "pre merger" in simple English in this context?

Comment: The companies come together (merge) to form a single larger business entity.  "Post-merger" refers to the contemplated larger entity, that is, the entity that would exist after the merger. "Post" means "after".  "Pre" means "before".

Comment: The body of your question should have more than a blurb of quoted text. At the very least, restate your question instead of leaving it in your title. Also, you are asking about terms that can be found in the dictionary, under [pre-](http://www.onelook.com/?w=pre-), [post-](http://www.onelook.com/?w=post-), and [merger](http://www.onelook.com/?w=merger), without giving even a hint of evidence about what research you performed or why you are still confused after trying to at least look up the words.

Answer (score 1):

'Post-merger' means after the merger, so 'the post-merger company' means 'the company as it will be after the merger'.

'Pre-merger' means before the merger.